# Вызов метода из Fragment

Tags: android, java

Как вызвать метод второго класса из первого? Они оба наследуются от разных классов, но почему-то один не видит другого.

**Обновление**

В Java нет таких понятий как глобальные переменные и методы, а также локальные, или есть? Почему-то он не может увидеть метод, при попытке вызвать его из первого класса, при этом методы класса, от которого он наследуется видит, а те которые у наследника не видит.

http://ideone.com/xc4JK4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому, что вызываемый метод не статичный, а стало быть, для его вызова нужен экземпляр класса. Либо создавайте/передавайте в параметрах экземпляр нужного класса для работы с ним, либо пометьте метод как `static`.

P.S. А вы не пробовали хотя бы сообщения компилятора читать, чтобы не задавать подобных вопросов?

Comment: Тогда getActiviti нелезя будет использовать

Comment: Вот код...закоминтил все
http://ideone.com/xc4JK4

Comment: @xTIGRx, попробуйте полностью прочитать мой ответ. Там написано, что вы можете так же передавать экземпляры нужного класса в параметрах метода/конструктора. И да, в коде по ссылке, что приведена выше, никаких фрагментов нет и в помине, так что переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: P.S. А вы не пробовали хотя бы сообщения компилятора читать, чтобы не задавать подобных вопросов?...вот вам ошибка компиля, и что это дает...Non-static method 'getActivity()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 1):

Потому что он не статичный. Во втором классе `static` для метода напишите.

Comment: Дак если он статичным будет, то в самом классе нелезя будет добавить textView через getActivity